# удаления из списка элементов класса list<classT> С++

Tags: c++, список, stl, std-list

здраствуйте, есть список с элементов класса
код класса:

```
class file_data
{
public:
string name;
string date;
int count;
file_data(string _name = " ", string _date = " ", int _count = 0)
{
    name = _name;
    date = _date;
    count = _count;
}
void set_name(string _name){ name = _name; }
void set_date(string _date){ date = _date; }
void set_count(int _count){ count = _count; }
string get_name(){ return name; }
string get_date(){ return date; }
int get_count(){ return count; }
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, file_data& fd)
{
    cout << "Назва файлу: " << fd.name << endl;
    cout << "Дата створення: " << fd.date << endl;
    cout << "Кількість звернень: " << fd.count << endl;
    return os;
}
};
```

оформлен так:

```
list<file_data> lst;
```

а так же итератор для него:

```
list<file_data>::iterator iter;
```

еще есть временный элемент класса

```
file_data tmp;
```

так вот при попытке удаления элементов таким образом(код ниже) пишет что   бинарный "==": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "file_data" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

```
file_data remove;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (iter = lst.begin(); iter != lst.end(); iter++)
    {
        tmp = *iter;
        if (tmp.date < user_date) remove = tmp;
    }
    lst.remove(remove);
}
```

сперва пробывал в одном цыкле, так же ошыбка и решил, что лучше за цыклом удалять, но если сделать так

```
list<file_data>::iterator remove;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for (iter = lst.begin(); iter != lst.end(); iter++)
    {
        tmp = *iter;
        if (tmp.date < user_date) remove = iter;
    }
    lst.erase(remove);
}
```

то программа компилируется, но во время выполнения операции идет прерывания и пишет list iterator not incrementable
подскажите как удалять элементы в моем случае или поправьте если я где то допустил ошибку

Comment: Следует 1) осознать, в чем заключалась проблема в первом методе 2) поглядеть, в какой ситуации итератор может стать не валидным во втором методе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что лучше использовать `list::remove_if` -

```
lst.remove_if([user_date](const file_data& f){f.date < user_date});
```

В любом случае, непонятно, зачем вы копируете:

```
tmp = *iter;
if (tmp.date < user_date)
```

Если

```
if (iter->date < user_date)
```

и короче, и эффективнее?

Comment: за iter->data спасибо, что то затупил и не знал даст ли доступ к даным, а так то решил проблему уже по другому, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

сделал так и все работает, если кому нужно будет

```
list<file_data>::iterator remove;
bool del = true;
while (del)
{
    for (iter = lst.begin(); iter != lst.end(); iter++)
    {
        tmp = *iter;
        del = false;
        if (tmp.date < user_date)
        {
            remove = iter; 
            del = true;
        }
    }
    if (del) lst.erase(remove);
}
```

скорее всего проблема была в лишних проходах и лишних удалениях соответственно

Comment: И получается что-то типа O(n*m) - т.е. для каждого удаляемого элемента крутить весь цикл... Вы бы хоть по достижении `del=true` цикл прерывали. Есть же `remove_if`, он сам по всем элементам пройдет - и только один раз.

Comment: ну я только с о списками разбираюсь и делаю как понятней, к тому же у меня нет ограничаний на сложность алгоритмов в программе, можно хоть по каждом ифами пройтись главное чтоб работало) но спасибо, буду учиться)